# Remove personal images from Stack Overflow account

Tags: support, profile-page, images, privacy

I am unable to remove my image that for some reason is being linked to my Stack Overflow account.

I went in to User Edit and changed the image to the default image (no face) but I can not find the option to remove the other images that could be selected from my Stack Overflow account.

Can someone please advise how I do this and also remove the image from the main profile of my account where the unwanted image is still showing.

Comment: All I see in your profile is the auto-generated identicon.  Gravatar may be hosting those images; have you tried over there?  Failing that, [contact Stack Exchange directly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).

Comment: That is strange as I just had someone else check the link to my profile and they see my facebook image.  The identicon is what I set it to once I realised that my profile image was changed.  But I can not find any option to remove images from my stackoverflow account.  Is there one ?

Comment: Gravatar is very heavily cached.  It might take an hour or two for the image to disappear completely.

Comment: Sounds like your browser is caching the profile page. I can't reproduce seeing your facebook image. Try CTRL+F5 to force taking fresh version.

Comment: Is this fixed? I don't see your profile picture anywhere as of now (it all shows the default generated avatar).

Comment: I thought of that too and also checked using another browser and still does not make sense when another visitor that does not have an account views my profile on their phone sees my image still

Comment: Maybe because it's still not updated in your [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/1233962/jason-carroll). When logged in there, you should see "Sync with oldest profile" link - click it and it should fix things

Comment: @Shadow-Wizard  Thank you that was what I had not done.  When I read that part I assumed it would reload the old profile I had before, meaning the old photos that I previously had, so did not touch it.  All sorted and how I would like it.

Comment: Cheers, so all is good now? Looks like a minor bug, that the network profile is not auto syncing when you change only the picture.